# Why are aws-sam function folders missing and why do images only appear in docker "default" context?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-desktop, ubuntu-22.04, aws-sam-cli

OS: Linux Ubuntu-Budgie 22.04 jammy with Budgie Desktop 10.6.1-1ubuntu3
SAM CLI, version 1.84.0
Docker version 23.0.6, build ef23cbc431
Docker Desktop 4.19.0 (106363)

I am trying to use AWS SAM to build a repo of lambda functions in containers. When I run the `sam build --use-container --parameter-overrides somethingSecret=<secretValue>` command. It seems to run correctly but the `.aws-sam -> build` folder doesn't contain the function folders, which the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/using-sam-cli-build.html) says should be there. I don't believe the `build.toml` file is correct either:

```
[function_build_definitions]
[function_build_definitions.074afb20-dcb6-43b1-ae84-e7c3393befe7]
packagetype = "Image"
functions = ["BuildFunction"]

[function_build_definitions.074afb20-dcb6-43b1-ae84-e7c3393befe7.metadata]
Dockerfile = "Dockerfile"
DockerContext = "/home/<user>/<directory>/<lambda-repo>/BuildFunction"
DockerTag = "nodejs18.x"

[function_build_definitions.074afb20-dcb6-43b1-ae84-e7c3393befe7.metadata.DockerBuildArgs]
somethingSecret = "secretValue"
```

There is a similar block for each function and at the very end of the file:

```
[layer_build_definitions]
```

There is nothing after this point.

Along with the `build.toml` file, there is a `template.yaml` which just takes from the `template.yaml` file which I create. It looks something like this with a similar resources section for each function:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: 'SAM deployment template

  '
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 30
Parameters:
  somethingSecret:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
Resources:
  BuildPSD:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      Role: arn:aws:iam::974208700040:role/lambda_basic_execution
      MemorySize: 1408
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      ImageUri: buildpsd:nodejs18.x
    Metadata:
      DockerBuildArgs:
        somethingSecret: <secretValue>
      DockerContext: /home/<user>/<directory>/<lambda-repo>/BuildFunction
      DockerTag: nodejs18.x
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      SamResourceId: BuildFunction
```

along with the following and similar for each function:

```
Outputs:
  BuildFunction:
    Description: BuildFunction Lambda Function ARN
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
      - BuildFunction
      - Arn
```

When I run the `sam build` command as stated above, it produces the files as described (minus the function folders). It also produces images, but in the wrong context. I want the images to appear in my docker desktop but I can only find them when I switch `docker context` to `default` instead of `desktop-linux` where I would think it should go. The only way I can get images to appear in docker desktop is when I actually run `docker build`.

So to recap what seem to be multiple issues but may be related to one thing:

1. `.aws-sam -> build` folder doesn't contain function folders.
2. `build.toml` file not correct/complete
3. Images built with `sam build` only appear in `default` docker context and not `desktop-linux` context to be shown with docker desktop.

Any and all advice would be much appreciated.